# When booking flights/holidays through sites like Expedia, what does the email say?

Tags: travel-agents, expedia

I'm planning a holiday to Spain via Expedia. I was wondering, what does the confirmation email tell you?

It will be my first time booking a holiday by myself as I usually do it through an agency rather than online, so the more advice and information the better.

What is the process like during booking flights hotels and bundle deals and so forth with Expedia and other sites (mostly I want to know about Expedia)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry its a bit of a wall of text but here is a redacted version of one of my Expedia booking emails, the version you get on email is nicely formatted this is just a plain text dump of that.

This was for a combined flight and hotel, everything I need to check in for the flight and hotel is provided below, including going on to the airlines website to enter things like frequent flyer, seat reservations etc.    About the only thing it doesn't have which would be useful is which terminal the flights go from.

The booking process is pretty easy, just say where and when you want fly to, if they give you a list of hotels, pick the one you want, then pick a room option.   Once you have picked a room, you then can pick from a list of flights, choosing time, number of stops, each choice is priced accordingly.

START OF BOOKING EMAIL

Newark
26 May 2017 - 1 Jun 2017   |   Itinerary # xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

This email can be used as an E-Ticket.

Itinerary #     xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

To get the most up-to-date version of your trip, go to your online itinerary and print a copy to take with you.

Important Information
To manage your booking or check in online (where available) please visit our Manage my Flight page, select your airline and use the booking reference provided below.

All passengers travelling to the US must provide valid travel documents and details of their full US destination address for US Immigration.

Proof of citizenship is required for international travel. Be sure to bring all necessary documentation (e.g. passport, visa, transit permit). To learn more, visit our Visa and Passport page . For local destination and health advice, check the Foreign and Commonwealth Office website .

If your plans change and you need to change or cancel your booking (subject to the applicable Rules & Restrictions below) please call us at 0330 123 1235

Price Summary
Flight + Hotel      £x,266.75
Total Price £x,266.75

All prices include taxes & fees and are quoted in British pounds sterling.

London (LHR) ? Newark (EWR)
26 May 2017 - 1 Jun 2017 , 2 return tickets

CONFIRMED

British Airways xxxxxx

Expedia.co.uk Booking ID    xxxxxx

Your reservation is booked and confirmed. There is no need to call us to reconfirm this reservation.

Traveller Information

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Adult   No frequent flyer details provided  Ticket # xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Adult   No frequent flyer details provided  Ticket # xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

- Seat assignments, special meals, frequent flyer point awards and special assistance requests should be confirmed directly with the airline.

26 May 2017 - Departure Direct  Total travel time: 7 h 45 m
Expedia Special Fare

London  Newark  7 h 45 m 
LHR  10:35  EWR  13:20
British Airways  185
Premium Economy (T) | Confirm seats with the airline *
31 May 2017 - Return Direct Total travel time: 7 h 5 m
Expedia Special Fare

New York    London  7 h 5 m 
JFK  22:55  LHR  11:00 +1 day   (Arrives on 1 Jun 2017)
This flight departs from JFK not EWR
British Airways  182
Premium Economy (T) | Confirm seats with the airline *

Airline Rules & Regulations
We understand that sometimes plans change. We do not charge a cancel or change fee. When the airline charges such fees in accordance with its own policies, the cost will be passed on to you.
Tickets are non-refundable, non-transferable and name changes are not allowed.
Please read important information regarding airline liability limitations.

Additional Flight Services
The airline may charge additional fees for checked baggage or other optional services.

Room Mate Grace Boutique Hotel
26 May 2017 - 31 May 2017
BOOKED
Your reservation is booked. No need to call us to reconfirm this reservation.

View hotel details
125 W 45th St, New York, NY, 10036 United States of America
Tel: 1 (212) 354-2323, Fax: 1 (212) 302-8585

Check-in

Check-in time starts at 3 PM
Check-in time ends at midnight
Minimum check-in age is 18
Your room/unit will be guaranteed for late arrival.
Important Hotel Information

This reservation is non-refundable and cannot be cancelled or changed.
View your online itinerary for additional rules and restrictions.
Room        Standard Queen Room - Non-Refundable

Includes: Free Wireless Internet

Reserved for

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

2 adults
Requests
1 bed, non-smoking room

Additional Hotel Services
The below fees and deposits only apply if they are not included in your selected room rate.

The following fees and deposits are charged by the property at time of service, check-in, or check-out.

Fee for continental breakfast: USD 16 per person (approximately)
The above list may not be comprehensive. Fees and deposits may not include tax and are subject to change.
Need help with your reservation?
Visit our Customer Support page.
Call us at 0330 123 1235
For faster service, mention itinerary #xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

When you book packaged deals, like flights + hotels, Expedia first gives you hotel options, with prices. Once you've selected that, it switches to flights, and tells you how much more is required for the flights. Then you have a summary, with dates, hotel, flights etc, and the total.

Once you've paid you receive a confirmation email with the flights and the hotel in two separate section.

Note that if you start with booking flights, Expedia gives you an option to add a hotel, too. And/or a car.